# Do unit testing files increase app size for released version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, app-store

Needed to know whether including unit testing into the app will affect the size of released version once it's ready for production.

If YES, Is there a way to not include unit testing files during release phase of the app like some sort of build script ?

Comment: no it does not. the tests are not bundled into the ipa as its a different target.

Comment: @Scriptable you should move your comment into an answer

Comment: @kd02, done. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it does not.

The test source files are not bundled into the IPA file as it is a different target.